# Sporadic SSRS Report Performance

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I have an SSRS instance with a dashboard report that frequently runs 100-200 times per minute throughout the organization. Most of the time, the report runs quickly with consistent times for data retrieval, processing, and rendering. The rowcounts don't vary much.

[image: Query results - ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog3]

On some occasions, the report experiences poor performance. Data retrieval times increase a bit. Processing and rendering times increase dramatically. However, the number of report executions and the rowcounts don't change much.

[image: Query results - ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog3]

Solarwinds Database Performance Analyzer is monitoring the SQL instance that hosts the SSRS databases. During the periods of poor report performance, DPA shows stored proc `ReportServer.dbo.CheckSessionLock` is generating a large number of `LCK_M_S` waits and stored procedure `ReportServer.dbo.WriteLockSession` is generating a large number of `LCK_M_X` waits.

[image: Solarwinds DPA - Top Waits]

Not surprisingly, there is a spike in the number of blocked sessions (along with a corresponding increase in the number of active sessions):

[image: Solarwinds DPA Sessions]

Within the SSRS log files I see this error during the periods of poor performance:

> ERROR: Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException:
>   ,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException:
>   The report server cannot open a connection to the report server
>   database. A connection to the database is required for all requests
>   and processing. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout
>   expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection
>   from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections
>   were in use and max pool size was reached.

The main report has 14 sub-reports, and they all use two shared data sources. I've edited the connection string to include the `max pool size` parameter. I've incremented the value from 150 to 250 to 1,000 to 2,000 and finally to 4,000. I have not tried 0 yet (unlimited). Increasing the parameter has not made any perceived improvement to the situation.

As for the sub-reports, it's my understanding their executions are not logged directly in `ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog3`. The `[AdditionalInfo]` column of XML data has some info that can be parsed out. But the info I found was for data retrieval times, not processing or rendering time. Even looking at the data retrieval times (which only have a slight to moderate increase during the poor performance periods), I do not see any indication of a specific sub-report being the culprit.

Other Notes:
The SQL Server instance hosting the SSRS databases is a dedicated instance--there are no other user databases.
SSRS data sources generally are connections to another SQL instance on a different server.

I'm not sure what the problem is. Is there something wrong with the SSRS/SQL environment? Or is the report design the problem?

> **UPDATE** 
> It has dawned on me that the `max pool size` parameter that I set for the shared data sources has nothing to do with the "Timeout
>   expired" error message. That is referring to the connection to the SQL
>   Server instance that hosts the [ReportServer] database (not the SQL
>   Server instance that hosts the database for the report data source). I
>   have looked for a way to change connection string parameters for the
>   SSRS service, but the connection string info is encrypted and stored
>   within file `RSReportServer.config` in the <Dsn> node. The connection
>   can be changed via the [rsconfig.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/rsconfig-utility-ssrs) utility. But it does not
>   appear to offer a way to set every connection string parameter.
>
> Here is what's going on with SQL client connections from the SSRS
>   service executable to the [ReportServer] database, according to
>   Perfmon:
>
> [image]
>
> Under normal conditions, there are 80-100 pooled connections and about
>   10 active connection pools. Report performance started to suffer at
>   6:36pm. Over the course of the next 8-10 minutes, the number of pooled
>   connections ramped up to over 2,000. But the number of connection
>   pools stayed roughly the same. Shortly after 6:45pm, the SSRS service
>   restarted.
>
> If the SSRS service executable creates connections with the default
>   `max pool size` of 10, I can see where there would be a problem. If
>   the parameter could be pushed to a higher number, would SSRS
>   eventually "right the ship"? Or would it simply prolong the agony and
>   delay an inevitable restart of the service?

Comment: Yeah, after a little investigation I see my answer won't help in this instance.

Comment: the error message is intriguing. perfmon data for the [\.NET Data Provider for SqlServer(*)\*] counters might at least illuminate what is behind the message.  since you've increased the pool size without it helping, i suspect a number of stale connections might be built up.